# How do I get a base class for my protobuf-net classes

Tags: protobuf-net

I have read the various posts to do with inheritance and that Protocol Buffers does not support inheritance. I don't want inheritance in the Protocol Buffers messages but rather inheritance so I can deal with all my Protocol Buffers messages easily.

I am using protobuf-net 2.0.0.480 and a .proto file to define my protocol. It all works well except when I get to the point where I would like a common ancestor so that I can do some common functionality and allow for easy inspection. A simple example:

My .proto file:

```
message ProtocolInformation {
  enum MessageKinds {
    LAYOUT_ADVANCE = 1;
    LAYOUT_RENDER = 2;                             
  }
  required MessageKinds MessageKind = 1;  
  required int32 UniqueID = 2;            
} 

message GFX_Layout_Advance {
  required ProtocolInformation ProtocolInfo = 1;
  required int32 LayoutHandle = 2;
}

message GFX_Layout_Render {
  required ProtocolInformation ProtocolInfo = 1;
  required int32 LayoutHandle = 2;
  required int32 Stage = 3;
}
```

which ultimately generates classes for GFX_Layout_Advance, GFX_Layout_Render as (only a portion of GFX_Layout_Advance) shown:

```
[global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name = @"GFX_Layout_Advance")]
public partial class GFX_Layout_Advance : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
    public GFX_Layout_Advance() { }

    private GFX_Protocol.ProtocolInformation _ProtocolInfo;
    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name = @"ProtocolInfo", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
    public GFX_Protocol.ProtocolInformation ProtocolInfo
```

As it was a partial class and there appeared to be no overrideable constructor I implemented:

```
public partial class GFX_Layout_Advance : GfxProtocolMessageBase
    {
        public override ProtocolInformation ProtocolInformation()
        {
            return ProtocolInfo;
        }
    }
```

This would allow me to treat all incoming messages as GfxProtocolMessageBase and allow querying of ProtocolInformation so that I can cast to the appropriate descendant. In this case  GFX_Layout_Advance. However.....

- Adding the additional partial class GFX_Layout_Advance() causes a different protobuf encoding. As the only change to the interface is a method I don't understand why this is?

Bottom line is:

1. I want to introduce a common base ancestor to all the generated protobuf-net classes
2. Base ancestor class will allow me access to information about what kind of message I am dealing with as I don't want to have to cast to the actual message type until I am ready

How do I achieve 1. & 2.?

All pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes that should work fine as long as `GfxProtocolMessageBase` is not a contract type. It uses partial classes deliberately to allow this type of thing. The encoded data should not change. If you have a scenario that misbehaves that I can look at I will happily investigate.
2. That's fine; just: don't use `Serializer.Serialize<GfxProtocolMessageBase>` / `Serializer.Deserialize<GfxProtocolMessageBase>`, as the serializer *should not know* about `GfxProtocolMessageBase` (unless of course you're happy to, but that does mean you won't be following the existing `.proto` 100%). For serialization, either `Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize` or `typeModel.Serialize` (for example, `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Serialize`) will do the right thing automatically. For deserialization, you will need to know the actual target `Type`.

Of course, the alternative option is to *allow* `GfxProtocolMessageBase` to be known to the serializer as a base-type, and use protobuf-net's inbuilt inheritance support (`[ProtoInclude(...)]` etc) - but the problem then is: that won't map 100% to your .proto, as inheritance is implemented (by protobuf-net) as encapsulation, meaning: it will be written as though it is a base-message with a number of optional sub-message fields.

---

Edit to show type-resolver usage for reading different objects (of heterogeneous types) from a single stream:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
[ProtoContract]
class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Foo with Id=" + Id;
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Bar
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Bar with Name=" + Name;
    }
}
static class Program
{
    // mechanism to obtain a Type from a numeric key
    static readonly Dictionary<int, Type> typeMap = new Dictionary<int, Type>
    {
        {1,typeof(Foo)}, {2,typeof(Bar)}
    };
    static Type ResolveType(int key)
    {
        Type type;
        typeMap.TryGetValue(key, out type);
        return type;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        // using MemoryStream purely for convenience
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // serialize some random data (here I'm coding the outbound key
            // directly, but this could be automated)
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, new Foo { Id = 123 },
                PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, new Bar { Name = "abc" },
                PrefixStyle.Base128, 2);
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, new Foo { Id = 456 },
                PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, new Bar { Name = "def" },
                PrefixStyle.Base128, 2);

            // rewind (this wouldn't be necessary for a NetworkStream,
            // FileStream, etc)
            ms.Position = 0;

            // walk forwards through the top-level data
            object obj;
            while (Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(
                ms, PrefixStyle.Base128, ResolveType, out obj))
            {
                // note we overrode the ToString on each object to make
                // this bit work
                Console.WriteLine(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Thanks. I had some other bug that caused the unexpected serialization I was seeing. Not a protobuf-net issue. Serialization is being consumed by a Delphi deserializer successfully.
2. Still need to deserialize from the Delphi serialized content but don't expect that to be an issue.

With the above I have been able to fillow the .proto 100% which is what I wanted.

Comment: *For deserialization you will need to know the target type*.... Unfortunately I don't know what that will be as there are many messages all coming in on the same input stream. How do I get protobuf-net to automagically create one based on the bytes retrieved?

Comment: @TheEdge there is no *inbuilt* way for the protocol buffers specification to handle that. However, the trick here is to write this data with `SerializeWithLengthPrefix(output, obj, PrefixStyle.Base128, fieldNumber)`, where `fieldNumber` is per-type - i.e. `Foo` might be 1, `Bar` might be 2, etc. Then use `NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(input, PrefixStyle.Base128, typeResolver, out obj)`, where `typeResolver` returns `Foo` for 1, `Bar` for 2, etc. I can do a full example if you want.

Comment: @Mark If you have some simple example code I would appreciate it. How I handled this Delphi side is that given a valid protocol buffers byte stream my base class on that end is able to decode the message ProtocolInformation {} and then from that MessageKind tells me what type I need for decoding. Is there any way I could do a similair kind of thing C# side? So use protobuf-net to do the necessary "peek" of the byte stream to get the actual type I need?

Comment: @TheEdge added example in .NET terms via TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix. Re doing the same as your Delphi implementation: can you be more specific? protobuf-net doesn't have a "peek" feature on the raw reader API, but: there *is* a raw reader API, so it might be reasonable to use the raw reader for the outer portions, and `ProtoReader.ReadObject` for the internals. I would have to see exactly what your data looks like to say for sure, and I might need to expose the *keys* - but *fundamentally* all the pieces are there.

Comment: added the full explanation of my .proto and resulting byte stream and what I mean wrt to the "Peek" requirement.

Comment: Looks like my edit is yet to be approved from peer review.... Would you mind if I sent you the code directly?

Comment: @TheEdge if you were editing your own post, it wouldn't have needed review; I can't see a pending edit on mine. But sure, my contact details are on my profile page

Comment: With Marc's help I was able to get the implementation I needed. Thanks again Marc.